# Ошибка десериализации тела сообщения на сервисе WCF

Tags: c#, json, post, wcf, rest

Есть сервис на WCF. Должен выполнять роль REST сервиса.

Есть книга.

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

Есть интерфейс добавления книги.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                               UriTemplate = "AddBook/{id}")]
    string AddBook(Book newBook, string id);
```

Метод этого интерфейса.

```
    public string AddBook(Book newBook, string id)
    {

        //Book newBook = repository.AddNewBook(book);
        if (book == null)
            return "id = " + id;//newBook.BookId;
        else
            return "asd" + book;
    }
```

GET, DELETE запросы проходят на ура. С POST проблемы. 
 [image: Посыл]

Ответ 200. Но получаю что объект пустой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы данные передаёте как Form Data, а серсис ожидает Json.

Comment: Посылаю вот это {"BookId":1,"ISBN":"123456","Title":"First"}. Ответ 200. Но получаю что объект null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. В описание интерфейса нужно было использовать

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```